# Getting Unsupported Media Type for .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, backend

I'm new in backend development and Gettig **415 Unsupported Media** Type in multipart API written in .net core. I have attached the postman image for your reference. Thanks in advance.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("uploadFiles")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<status>>> UploadFilesAsync([FromBody] UploadFile uploadFile)
    {

        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client("Access key", "Secret key", Region))
        {
            status s = new status();
            try
            {

                if (uploadFile.Image != null && uploadFile.Image.Length > 0 && uploadFile.Name != null && uploadFile.Name != "")
                {
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadFile.Image.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        uploadFile.Image.CopyTo(fileStream);

                        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                        {
                            InputStream = fileStream,
                            Key = uploadFile.Name,
                            BucketName = "needbucket",
                            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead

                        };

                        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
                        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);

                    }
                    s.Status = "1";
                    s.resone = "File uploded sucesefully.";
                    return Ok(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    s.Status = "0";
                    s.resone = "Image and Image name canot be blank";
                    return Ok(s);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                s.Status = "0";
                s.resone = "Somthing went wrong." + e.Message;
                return Ok(s);
            }

        }
    }
```

Getting in response on the postman.
[image]

Comment: Change your `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Change your `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`

2.In the Body tab, select the form-data option. Then hover your mouse over the row so you can see a dropdown appear that says Text. Click this dropdown and set it to File.

[image]

[image]

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

```
public class UploadFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }       
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }//this is my key name
       
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was using [FromBody]. After changing it to [FromForm] it worked. Thanks @Qing Guo.